# Is it possible to record or log specific topics in ROS2 without publishing?

Tags: ros2, rostopic, publish, logging, rosbag2

I apologize if this is a somewhat naive question, but I don't really know much about ros2's architecture beyond basic utilization.

I'm a student working in autonomous vehicle research, and my team seems to run into bandwidth issues with the sheer amount of data we publish from our sensor drivers (multiple cameras, gnss receivers, imus, lidar units, radar, and misc CAN messages).

We need to record nearly everything (w/ a timestamp!) for failure analysis and algorithm development, but we use a much smaller subset of the data for actual operation.

What is best practice for recording/logging messages that aren't needed for any process during operation?

Additionally, many of the topics we do publish and use only need to be accessed by a single node or object within a node. We'd still like to record these messages, but is there a more efficient way to access and record them than publishing?

Additional info:

- All sensors directly interface to the same computer.
- This computer handles all processing and recording.
- Running Ubuntu 20.04 and Galactic. (upgrading's in the works because MCAP)
- We cannot make any hardware changes. (Trust me, we'd love to.)
- Timestamps for time of reception are critical for data analysis and consolidation.
- We communicate with the car via a low-bandwidth rf connection during testing, so we construct and publish topics with the minimum necessary info to monitor its status, publishing them under their own domain id (I think). Again, recorded but only used to monitor at a base station.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no need to publish other than to log, you can directly write the messages to a bag instead, see the tutorial [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Advanced/Recording-A-Bag-From-Your-Own-Node-CPP.html).

An alternatively idea (just an idea, not tested) is to add a "logger node" to each process, and use [intra-process communication](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Demos/Intra-Process-Communication.html) so those nodes communicate without using network bandwidth.

EDIT: [DataTamer](https://discourse.ros.org/t/announcing-datatamer-beta-a-fearless-logging-library/35177) was just announced on the ROS Discourse, and might also be a solution to your problem.